# Saving Data in JSON Format using NODE

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, fs

I know this is asked many times but I couldn't find any code for same so I am adding mine and its output. Please take a look.

```
app.put('/hotel/save', function(req, res) {

    var fileToSave = 'savedHotelDetails.txt';
     res.send('Booking Id '+guid());
     res.status(200);
     var arr = [];
     var k;
     fs.readFile(fileToSave, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            k = [];
        } else {
            arr.push(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(req.query.params);
            console.log(obj);
            k = arr.push(obj);
            //JSON.stringify(k);
            //console.log(arr);
            fs.appendFile(fileToSave, JSON.stringify(arr),'utf8');
        }
     })
});
```

This gives me output as

```
["",{"hotelId":"IM50003"}]["[\"\",{\"hotelId\":\"IM50003\"}]",{"hotelId":"IB50002"}]["[\"\",{\"hotelId\":\"IM50003\"}][\"[\\\"\\\",{\\\"hotelId\\\":\\\"IM50003\\\"}]\",{\"hotelId\":\"IB50002\"}]",{"hotelId":"IB50002"}]
```

Firstly why this kind of output?
Secondaly, my goal is to make this call from front end with new data and want it to get append like

```
[{"ID": "IM5004"},{"ID": "IM5005"},{"ID": "IM5006"}]
```

The above data should be after three calls.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are reading the file content and pushing it to array and adding the new object to the array. Use `file.write` instead of `file.append`

ie instead of

```
 fs.appendFile(fileToSave, JSON.stringify(arr),'utf8');
```

use

```
 fs.write(fileToSave, JSON.stringify(arr),someCallbackfn)
```

Comment: Any "clean"  way to do this?

Comment: `json` is just a serialization technique, if you want want persistence then try to store in a db (mongo, json-file-store) or in your case use `.csv` format so that you can simply append extra records without much performance penalty. refer to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011343/nodejs-append-inside-json-file-in-array-format