# Appending JSON data to a file

Tags: json, file

I have some data I want to write to a file periodically and I'd like to write it small JSON objects. At a later time I'd like to read them all in for processing, but the appended file of JSON objects isn't JSON itself.

So I stringify the JSON object and write them to file periodically and I get something like this;

```
{
    "100": {
        "stuff": 123
    }
}
{
    "300": {
        "stuff": 456
    }
}
{
    "200": {
        "stuff": 789
    }
}
```

Of course when I try to parse the file with a simple script like the following;

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = 'test.log'

var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8'));

var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(obj);
});
```

...the parser freaks out because this isn't a valid JSON file, I'd need something more like;

```
{
    "100": {
        "stuff": 123
    },
    "300": {
        "stuff": 456
    },
    "200": {
        "stuff": 789
    }
}
```

...but I can't get this by simply appending records. I can of course force commas between the records before writing them, but I end up missing the '{' at the start of the file, the '}' at the end of the file and would have an extra ',' on the last record. The whole things reaks of being a kludge.

I'm guessing someone has worked all of this out alreadyand there is a nice pattern for this, but I couldn't find anything from searching. Each section will have a variable amount of data so I like the flexibility JSON offers, but I don't want to store it all ahead of time before writing to disk as it will get large.

If you could point me at a good solution for this it would be appreciated.

Sincerely, Paul.

Comment: Use a database?  Or  read and write lines of text, each being a json object...

Comment: The "normal" way of doing this sort of thing would be to use a database, rather than an JSON file, to store the intermediate values, then have code that produces a valid JSON object from the database. Is there a reason this sort of approach wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. You're right, a DB would be much better, I'd just hoped I could get away with something quick without having to set that all up (i.e. being lazy). I was just hoping I'd missed some pattern around this or there was a fault tolerant node module that would pull in the data despite the mistakes. Out side of this, I'd write a script to massage it into a compliant format, or just bite the bullet like you said and do the database.

Comment: Mark, I like your second idea. If I don't pretty the stringify its one one line and then I can read each line as a compliant json object. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011343/nodejs-append-inside-json-file-in-array-format). If you don't want to use database CSV might be a better option for tabular data than JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a regex before processing the object list file to add a comma. Since the pattern is a new line after every object, you could use this to find and replace: `/}\n{/g`.

For your sample, this should do the trick :

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var file = 'test.log'
var obj;

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  
  var jsonString = '[' + data.replace(/}\n{/g, '},{')+ ']'; // Adding brackets in order to create an array of objects
  
  obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Then, if you want to have an object as you specified you can use the spread operator `...` to append an object to your super-object :

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var file = 'test.log'
var obj;

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var jsonString = '[' + data.replace(/}\n{/g, '},{')+ ']'; // Adding brackets in order to creat an array of objects

  obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  var superObj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      superObj = {...superObj,...obj[i]};
  }

  console.log(superObj);

});
```

Comment: Nice! I haven't used spread operators before. I'd implemented another approach in the meantime based on what Mark said above, but that required the whole json record be on one line which was a lot less readable. Your solution fixes that, thanks.

Comment: Definitely a DB or a CSV file would be the best option! Glad it helped you :)